# Park Tool MT-40 with 11 speed chain

Tags: tools

I'm looking to buy the MT-40. The website states that it has a 10 speed compatible chain tool. Can this same tool work with my 11 speed chain (Shimano 105 (11 speed) group set so I think the chain is 11 speed). Is there any difference between 10 and 11 speed chain tools?

[image]

Comment: Just remember you carry tools for yourself only.  No need to carry tools for other people, unless you're a designated donkey in a group ride with people below your ability and you're handicapping yourself to make it more fair.   So take tools that fit your bike.

Comment: @Criggie , thanks for the tip. I personally have an 11 speed bike but I'm getting a good deal on this multi tool (almost 70% off) so if it works with my 11 speed I'll jump right on that deal. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just called Park Tool. They said the reason they don't advertise it as 11 speed is because it will not work with Campagnolo 11 speed due to the peening. However, for Shimano or SRAM it should be fine. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 4):

There are chain tools out there (for Shimano/SRAM) which are recommended for 10 speed but not 11 speed (and Campagnolo needs a 11 speed chain tool for peening); Pedros makes at least one which they [specifically mark this way](http://pedros.com/faqs/which-of-pedros-chain-tools-can-be-used-on-shimano-11-speed-chains/) (the ICM Multi Tool). The problem with using a chain tool not designed for 11 speed might be due to the dimensions of the rivets and how tight they are in there, the chain tool may warp the plates on the chain when putting in the new pin.

I'd suggest emailing Park Tool to ask, but I'd think they put 10 speed there for a reason.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Just wanted to check if anyone has used it with 11 speed before. The seller (used tool) says they will work but I'm not sure if using something it's not designed for is the best idea.

Comment: I just called Park Tool. They said the reason they don't advertise it as 11 speed is because it will not work with Campagnolo 11 speed due to the peening. However, for Shimano or SRAM it should be fine. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Abubakr - make that an answer & accept it. That will make it easier for others to find. Self-answering is perfectly acceptable, and I think Batman can spare the 15 points. ;)

Comment: @FreeMan , thanks, will do! It just makes me wait until tomorrow before I can accept it.